# Branch restrictions in git / Revoking copies of a git repo

Tags: git, permissions, repository, branch, bitbucket

I'm  trying to workout a workflow where changes need to be approved before they can be merged into the master branch.

One obvious solution is reject/approve pull requests. But the problem we have is that we don't want employees maintaining their own repos of the company code. Therefore, we have a company account/repo that everyone pushes to. Is there a way we can give users their own copy of the code under their account, but revoke access once they leave the company, so we can use pull requests effectively?

What are my other options around restricting commits to the branch.

We use bitbucket.

Answer (score 1):

Give employees access to the company repo, remove that access when they leave?

Developers aren't children; you can tell them "don't commit to master except via pull request" and reasonably expect them to do it.  If you can't, consider finding other developers.

Comment: But if someone clones the repo across to their own account, we dont have access to remove that clone from their account.

Comment: and if someone downloads all your code to their hard drive, you'd never even know about it.  if employees can work on your code, then employees can steal your code.  the only real mitigation is to try not to hire people who would steal your code.

Comment: Also: By definition a cloned repository on a local machine is in itself already a "complete" repository you have absolutely no control over. And that's a core feature of a DVCS.